# A question on the Lawvere theory of vector spaces

Tags: category-theory

> Let $k$ be a field and write $L$ for the Lawvere theory of $k$-vector spaces, which is the category of f.d. $k$-vector spaces.

By definition, models of $L$ in sets is the category of $k$-vector spaces.

What is the category of models in f.d. $k$-vector spaces? Is it $L$ itself?

Comment: May be as a new user you didn't know this, but deleting a question after getting an answer is considered rude here. The reason is that such antics deny the people who helped you a chance to get the "reward" of appreciation (in terms of upvotes). Don't do this. Ever. If there is an extremely pressing reason, flag the post, and explain the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Chasing through the definitions, a model of $L$ in $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ is ultimately a pair $(V, \rho)$ consisting of a $k$-vector space $V$ and a ring homomorphism $\rho : k \to \operatorname{End}(V)$.

Say that a *standard* model is one where $\rho(z)$ is scalar multiplication by $z$.

Now, consider $k = \mathbb{C}$ and the model $T = (\mathbb{C}, \rho)$ where $\rho(z) w = \bar{z}w$. Observe that this really is a ring morphism in $z$ and $\mathbb{C}$-linear in $w$.

**Theorem:** $T$ is not isomorphic to any standard model

**Proof:** Let $C$ be the standard model on $\mathbb{C}$. A morphism of models is completely determined by the map on underlying vector spaces. Suppose there were a homomorphism $f : T \to C$. Then, for each complex $z$ we have a commutative square

$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathbb{C} @> \rho(z) >> \mathbb{C}
\\ @VVfV @VVfV
\\ \mathbb{C} @> z >> \mathbb{C}
\end{CD} $$

Plugging in an arbitrary complex $w$ we conclude $ f(\bar{z}w) = z f(w) $, and consequently $ \bar{z} w f(1) = z w f(1) $.

Thus, we conclude that $f(1) = 0$. There does not exist any isomorphism $T \to C$. $\square$

Comment: @user43208: There is a functor from $L$ to the category of $L$-models in $L$, and I construct an $L$-model in $L$ that is not isomorphic to anything in the image of that functor.

Comment: Yes of course. I had glossed over something too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is to supplement the answer already given by Hurkyl.

It's true in this case that the Lawvere theory $L$ is equivalent to the category $\text{Vect}_{fd}$ of f.d. vector spaces (morally speaking it's opposite to this category -- the Lawvere theory is on general grounds opposite to the category of f.g. free algebras -- but here this category happens to be equivalent to its opposite via linear duality, so we're safe). The problem is to characterize the category of functors $L \to \text{Vect}_{fd}$ that preserve finite products. Or what is the same, functors $\text{Vect}_{fd} \to \text{Vect}_{fd}$ that preserve finite products, or such functors that preserve finite coproducts -- by linear duality there are various ways of thinking about it.

Now $\text{Vect}_{fd}$ is $\text{Ab}$-enriched, and coproduct- or biproduct-preserving functors $\text{Vect}_{fd} \to \text{Vect}_{fd}$ are the same as $\text{Ab}$-enriched functors. Moreover, $\text{Vect}_{fd}$ is, qua the $\text{Ab}$-enriched world,  the Cauchy completion of $k$ viewed as a one-object $\text{Ab}$-enriched category (the more general statement is that the $\text{Ab}$-enriched Cauchy completion of a ring $R$ is the category of f.g. projective $R^{op}$-modules). It follows that coproduct-preserving functors $\text{Vect}_{fd} \to \text{Vect}_{fd}$ are equivalent to $\text{Ab}$-enriched functors $k \to \text{Vect}_{fd}$. These are given by a finite-dimensional vector space $W$ and a ring homomorphism

$$k \to \text{Vect}_k(W, W).$$

In slightly different language: this data can be described as a $(k, k)$-bimodule (a left $k$- right $k$-bimodule) $W$ whose left $k$-module structure is finite-dimensional. In that case, viewing $\text{Vect}_{fd}$ as a category of left $k$-modules, we get a (co)product-preserving endofunctor as

$$W \otimes_k -: \text{Vect}_{fd} \to \text{Vect}_{fd}$$

and all product-preserving endofunctors are of this form.

It is clear that any finite-dimensional vector space $W$ gives such a bimodule (just pull back the $k$-scalar action along the map $k \otimes k \to k$ given by $k$-multiplication), but as Hurkyl's argument shows, these do not exhaust all such bimodules.

Comment: It's clear that sending $W$ to $W \otimes_k -$ gives a functor from $L$ to the category of $L$ models in $L$, but you haven't shown every model is of this form. In particular, you analyzed the action of a model $F$ on objects, but you've forgotten to look at its action on morphisms! If $r$ is a scalar (viewed as an endomorphism of $k$), then $F(r)$ need not be scalar multiplication by $r$ on $F(k)$, in which case $F(k) \otimes_k r$ is not isomorphic to $F(r)$.

Comment: In fact, your argument gives me the suspicion that you can identify the category of $L$-modules in $L$ with some subcategory of $(k,k)$-bimodules.

Comment: Hurkyl, you are absolutely right; mea culpa. Your response also shed light on what was going on in your own answer, so thanks. I've completely rewritten my answer.